# Why are tuples slower than lists at evaluating generators into themselves?

Tags: python, performance, list, tuples, python-internals

```
python -m timeit "tuple(xrange(600000))"
```

> 100 loops, best of 3: 11.5 msec per loop

```
python -m timeit "list(xrange(600000))"
```

> 100 loops, best of 3: 10.1 msec per loop

---

Comparing them with the [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) module:

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>> dis(lambda: tuple(xrange(600000)))
      0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (tuple)
      3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (xrange)
      6 LOAD_CONST               1 (600000)
      9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
     12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
     15 RETURN_VALUE

>>> dis(lambda: list(xrange(600000)))
      0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list)
      3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (xrange)
      6 LOAD_CONST               1 (600000)
      9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
     12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
     15 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: That's too small a difference to call, really. But lists are dynamic arrays, tuples are fixed sizes, so the latter require a precise size first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As iterators normally don't give you an up-front size, both tuples and lists need to use an overallocation strategy to handle arbitrary size iterables. As it stands, `xrange()` objects do have a `__len__` method, and the [`_PyObject_LengthHint()` function used](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/430236ef507b/Objects/abstract.c#l92) used by both tuples and lists will take advantage of this to set a correct target size, once. So in this case, the `list()` code is just subtly more efficient because it inlines iteration to avoid a `NULL` comparison.

Follow me through the code; the only real difference in this case is how the iterator is unwound and the values are copied across. Because `list()` and `tuple()` objects track different information, these loops are subtly different in implementation. See:

- [`PySequence_Tuple()`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/430236ef507b/Objects/abstract.c#l2188) is used for `tuple()`
- [`listextend()`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/430236ef507b/Objects/listobject.c#l870) used for `list()`

The `tuple()` code path uses `PyIter_Next()` while the `list()` code path inlines that to not have to test for `NULL` twice. Apart from that the loops do the same amount of work. I think it is that `NULL` test, amplified over 600000 iterations, that account for the time difference here.

In any case, the time difference you found is really not that big; repeated runs on my machine keep the difference in time within 10% (with `list` winning each time). The time difference increases linearly with the size of the `xrange()` used.

Comment: The extra `PyObject_LengthHint` call is also present in [`listextend`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a95a74aca4e/Objects/listobject.c#l834) when the passed object is not a list or tuple, though both use it for different purpose.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: yes, but the tuple allocation makes larger steps and the resizing actually has to remove the overallocation.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: complete rewrite, I found the issue here, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that this very much depends on your runtime. E.g. in cpython, both the list and tuple function are coded in C, and since lists are used very frequently, it is very probable that the list method has seen more optimizations than the tuple method.

Other implementations may behave differently.